# Magento 2 : Overide Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery Block

Tags: magento2, blocks, overrides

I am working on custom extension and need to override Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery block.

I have followed this method.

In di.xml,

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery" type="[Company]\[Vendor]\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Gallery"/>
```

In [Company][Vendor]\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Gallery.php

```
namespace [Company]\[Vendor]\Block\Catalog\Product\View;

class Gallery extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery
{

public function getGalleryImagesJson()
   {

        $imagesItems = [];
        foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $image) {
            $imagesItems[] = [
                'thumb' => $image->getData('small_image_url'),
                'img' => $image->getData('medium_image_url'),
                'full' => $image->getData('large_image_url'),
                'caption' => $image->getLabel(),
                'position' => $image->getPosition(),
                'isMain' => $this->isMainImage($image),
            ];
        }
        if (empty($imagesItems)) {
            $imagesItems[] = [
                'thumb' => $this->_imageHelper->getDefaultPlaceholderUrl('thumbnail'),
                'img' => $this->_imageHelper->getDefaultPlaceholderUrl('image'),
                'full' => $this->_imageHelper->getDefaultPlaceholderUrl('image'),
                'caption' => '',
                'position' => '0',
                'isMain' => true,
            ];
        }
     return json_encode($imagesItems);
    }
}
```

When I do this, More Views Images of the product is don't show any more.

Can you help me into this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: follow this link http://webkul.com/blog/overriding-block-model-controller-magento2/

Comment: Already try that, but when I override this block, more views images on product view page not show any more.

Comment: update you question what you tried

Comment: #Rajkumar .E my questions updated, can you please help me out into this.

Comment: any error are generated or not?

Comment: After override block  most viewed product doesn,t view in product page right?

Comment: yes, more view image not showing any more.
And No error generated in log file.

Comment: magento 2 have widget concepts, you need to add more view product  widget in product details page.

Comment: To use this overriding block do we need to change in layout too?

Comment: @muasif80 I suggest you used plugin functionality as I describe in answer.

Comment: Yes thanks. I have used that successfully. But I am concerned that why is that so we are not able to override the block using preference? Perhaps it does not meet the defined rules for block overriding feature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution. I am doing the same thing by using the plugin functionality of magento2.

For that in di.xml file specify plugin.

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery">
        <plugin name="plugin_block_catalog_product_view_gallery"
                type="[Company]\[Vendor]\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Gallery"
                sortOrder="10"
                disabled="false"/>
 </type>
```

It is better to used.

Comment: Hi Dhiren, I am trying the plugin method but on my plugin function afterGetGalleryImagesJson(), I want the product data, how can i do that. $this->getProduct(); didn't work. can you help please

Comment: @aton1004 Can you tell me what you have try? And what you try to archive?

Comment: thanks for the reply, actually i wanted product data to check some attribute value before making some changes to the result of gallery , I got it from registry