# override Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery using preference not working

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am trying to override the **getGalleryImagesJson()** method of Class **Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery** but I am unable to do so.

Below are my codes:

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery" type="Custom\Catalogoverride\Block\Product\View\Gallery" />
</config>
```

**My overriden file**

```
<?php 
namespace Custom\Catalogoverride\Block\Product\View;


    class Gallery extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery
        {
            /**
     * Retrieve product images in JSON format
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getGalleryImagesJson()
    {
        die('here');
        //var_dump('here');die();
        $imagesItems = [];
        foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $image) {
            $imagesItems[] = [
                'thumb' => $image->getData('small_image_url'),
                'img' => $image->getData('medium_image_url'),
                'full' => $image->getData('large_image_url'),
                'caption' => $image->getLabel(),
                'position' => $image->getPosition(),
                'isMain' => $this->isMainImage($image),
            ];
        }
        if (empty($imagesItems)) {
            $imagesItems[] = [
                'thumb' => $this->_imageHelper->getDefaultPlaceholderUrl('thumbnail'),
                'img' => $this->_imageHelper->getDefaultPlaceholderUrl('image'),
                'full' => $this->_imageHelper->getDefaultPlaceholderUrl('image'),
                'caption' => '',
                'position' => '0',
                'isMain' => true,
            ];
        }
        return json_encode($imagesItems);
    }
        }
?>
```

I am not getting up this file. I have tried same way to override other methods of checkout module which worked but not this time.

I have found similar question [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/135463/magento-2-overide-magento-catalog-block-product-view-gallery-block) but it followed the approach of **plugin** but I need to do it using **preference**.

Can anyone suggest why it is not working from this method.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you add `<sequence><module name="Magento_Catalog"/></sequence>` in your module.xml file

Comment: Where is located your di.xml file?

Comment: @MeenakshiSundaramR do i have to add that? I have override the checkout block which didn't required the sequence node, but i will give it a try.

Comment: @MaxStsepantsevich di.xml is inside etc directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting my fix so that it could help others. As the preference didn't work for me I used plugin to get it done.

My **di.xml** file looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="Custom_Catalogoverride_Plugin_Magento_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Gallery" sortOrder="10" type="Custom\Catalogoverride\Plugin\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Create a class named gallery on the above mentioned file. It looks like this.

```
<?php 
namespace Custom\Catalogoverride\Plugin\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View;

class Gallery
{

    public function afterGetGalleryImagesJson(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        //your code here
    }
}
```

Now if you dump **$result** you will get the data returned by **GetGalleryImagesJson()** method.I created my own result and returned that. Also I needed the product data in this file to have some condition so what i did was i get the product from the registry. here is what i did.

```
<?php


namespace Custom\Catalogoverride\Plugin\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View;

class Gallery
{

    public function afterGetGalleryImagesJson(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        //your code here
        $om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $registry = $om->get('Magento\Framework\Registry');
        $product = $registry->registry('product');  
        //now use this product object to get product info if you need to do some processing
        //let's say i need to check the product id and return the default place holder image url
        $id = $product->getId();
        if($id=="something"){
            //get the placeholder image url
            $scopeconfig = $om->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface');
            $storeManager = $om->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager');
            //get media url
            $mediaUrl = $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA );
            //create full placeholder image url
            $placeholderUrl = $mediaUrl.'catalog/product/placeholder/'.$scopeconfig->getValue('catalog/placeholder/image_placeholder');

        $imagesItems[] = [                
                'thumb' => $placeholderUrl,
                'img' => $placeholderUrl,
                'full' => $placeholderUrl,
                'caption' => '',
                'position' => '0',
                'isMain' => true,
            ];
            $result = json_encode($imagesItems);
        }   
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Check the comments to get broad idea what I did. Also if if you want further information on Plugins check [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html).

**Note:** I used objectmanager to create the object it is not the proper way the best way is to do with dependency injection but for now i couldn't implement that here so i used the quick fix. if you can use it please let me know.

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

```
@MeenakshiSundaramR do i have to add that? I have override the checkout block which didn't required the sequence node, but i will give it a try.
```

yes, thats pretty important especially when you have a preference change in you di.xml.

The sequence in the module.xml is used to define the order, in which the modules are loaded.

So it could be, that in one module (checkout) the preference works without the sequence node (if you are lucky with the module loading order) and in another case, it doesn't (because your less lucky)

Comment: I have added the sequence node but still not working